# AWS Resource Usage Data - CPU, Memory and Disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to build an analytics Dashboard using the below Metrics/KPIs for all the EC2 Instance.

1. Total CPU vs CPUUtilized
2. Total RAM vs RAMUtilized
3. Total EBS Volume vs EBSUtilized.

For example, I have lunch an EC2 instance with 4 CPU, 16GiB RAM and 50GB SSD, I would like to know the above KPIs in a time series trend. I am not getting any clue on where to get the data from EC2. Tried the EC2 instance metrics through CloudWatch using **boto3** client, however did not get the above Metrics. I would like to know :

1. Where to find the data with above Metrics ?
2. Need the above metrics data in s3 on an daily basis.

Similarly is there a way to get similar metrics for AWS RDS and AWS EKS Cluster ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon EC2 service collects information about the **virtual machine (instance)** and sends it to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

See: [List the available CloudWatch metrics for your instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html)

Note that it only collects metrics that can be observed from the virtual machine itself -- CPU Utilization, network traffic and Amazon EBS traffic. The EC2 service cannot see what is happening 'inside' the instance, since **it is the Operating System that controls memory and manages the contents of the disks**.

If you wish to collect metrics from the Operating System, then you would need to [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html). This agent runs in the instance and sends metrics out to CloudWatch.

You can write code that calls the [CloudWatch Metrics APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html) to retrieve metrics. Note that the metrics returned are calculated over a time period (eg average CPU Utilization over a 5-minute period). It is not possible to retrieve the actual raw datapoints.

See also:

- [Monitoring Amazon RDS metrics with Amazon CloudWatch - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html)
- [Amazon EKS and Kubernetes Container Insights metrics - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-EKS.html)